# Cocoa: how to unarchive a NSMutableAttributedString with archived attributes?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring, nskeyedunarchiver

I try to unarchive an archived `NSMutableAttributedString` in a macos-app, written in swift. I get back the text but without any attributes. The attributes are in the exported serialisation but it is *ignored* by `NSMutableAttributedString(coder: unarchiver)!`

Let's dive in: first I create a AttributedString and format one word with a red background:

```
let content = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Dogs like to play with balls.")
content.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor: NSColor.red], range: NSMakeRange(5, 4))
```

Then I serialise it with a `NSKeyedArchiver`:

```
let archiver = NSKeyedArchiver(requiringSecureCoding: false)
archiver.outputFormat = .xml
content.encode(with: archiver)
archiver.finishEncoding()
```

I stored the result in a variable:

```
let serialisedData = archiver.encodedData
```

to write it back into a new `NSMutableAttributedString`:

```
let unarchiver = try NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingFrom: serialisedData)
let restored = NSMutableAttributedString(coder: unarchiver)!
```

the `restored` AttributedString does not have any formations. :-(

Is there is a way to restore the attributes? I can see that the color information is in the `serialisedData` stream. I tried `outputFormat` with `.xml` and `.binary` with same results.

Here is the Playground output:
[image: Playground]

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

```
let archiver = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: content, requiringSecureCoding: false)
```

and

```
let restored = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: NSMutableAttributedString.self, from: archiver)
```

Doh!